# How to debug outline is not working in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I started a fresh vue3 project with vuetify3 via vue cli.

```
$ vue create playground-vuelidate
$ cd playground-vuelidate
$ code .
$ vue add vuetify
$ npm run serve
```

## FormInput.vue

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
          <v-combobox :items="select1" label="Select1" chips></v-combobox>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
          <v-text-field
            outline
            v-model="input1"
            :rules="rules"
            label="Input1"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
          <v-text-field
            outline
            v-model="input2"
            :rules="rules"
            label="Input2"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
          <v-text-field outline v-model="input3" label="Input3"></v-text-field>
          <v-textarea
            v-model="v$.textarea1.$model"
            :class="status(v$.textarea1)"
            label="textarea1"
          ></v-textarea>
          <pre>{{ $v }}</pre>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
import { maxLength, required } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";

export default {
  name: "UsersPage",
  data: () => ({
    select1: ["Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Buzz"],
    input1: "",
    input2: "222",
    input3: "333",
    textarea1: "12345678910",
    rules: [
      (value) => !!value || "Required.",
      (value) => (value || "").length <= 20 || "Max 20 characters",
    ],
  }),
  setup: () => ({ v$: useVuelidate() }),
  validations() {
    return {
      textarea1: {
        required,
        minlength: maxLength(20),
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    status(validation) {
      return {
        error: validation.$error,
        dirty: validation.$dirty,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5a5;
  background: #efe;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8e8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #fdd;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #f99;
}
</style>
```

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="1000">
    <FormInput />
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn text color="gray accent-4"> Cancel </v-btn>
      <v-btn color="primary"> Submit </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import FormInput from "./components/FormInput.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    FormInput,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

It yields this result

[image]

It supposes to look like this.

[Official Doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/)
[image]

---

## Notes

I have a select, inputs, and textarea all 3 of them the outline CSS doesn't seem to work or applied. Is it a known Vuetify bug ?

Comment: Vuetify 3 documentation is at https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
<v-text-field
  outlined
></v-text-field>
```

not

```
<v-text-field
  outline
></v-text-field>
```

This is based from vuetify for vue3
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/